# How to get lists are made up of the specific list

Tags: python

Now i have three list(A list,B list,C list)

I want to find the index of element which list B's element in list A and list C's element in list A.

Example:

```
 B=['a','b','c','e','c'] 
 C=['c','d','d','a','a']

 A=['a','c','d']
```

The B list's first element and the C list's first element both in list,it's the index 0 which i wanted.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, can you add a snippet with the result you're expecting?

Comment: I want get index=[0 2 4]

Comment: You can understand that there are many cities right, I just specify the city of the city right

Comment: What do you mean by "not concise"?

Comment: I still don't understand your question, how do those inputs return 0,2,4? what have you tried?

Comment: it is too much code,sorry for my poor english

Comment: thx,the following answer is what I want

Answer (score 0):

Simply use list comprehension:

```
citypair1=['a','b','c','e','c'] 
citypair2=['c','d','d','a','a']

city=['a','c','d']

[i for i in range(len(citypair1)) if citypair1[i] in city and citypair2[i] in city]
```

or arguably more pythonic:

```
[i for i,(c1,c2) in enumerate(zip(citypair1,citypair2)) if c1 in city and c2 in city]
```